# Utility function and consumer's optimal demand (edited)

Tags: microeconomics

Derive the consumer's optimal demand of x and y, respectively, when the budget constraint is
$px + qy = m $   and the utility function is`u = $x^p + y^p$

here's my attempt but i'm lost on how to solve for $x$. Can someone please help with simple and easy to follow instructions?

[image]

I'm lost after that. Please help me with steps. The answer for
$x=$ $((p/q))^((1/(p-1))$ * $y$.

that's supposed to be power of $^(1/p-1)$ btw. i can solve the rest but idk where the power of $^(1/p-1)$ came from.

Comment: Hi! Unless there is a typo here, this is not a Cobb-Douglas utility function. Also, are you sure the powers in the function are exactly equal to the price of good $x$, that is, $p$? If yes, are there any restrictions on this parameter? Please check your question for typo's and edit where necessary.

Comment: @Giskard Hi, I fixed it. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: Are you sure the powers in the function are exactly equal to the price of good $x$, that is, $p$? If yes, are there any restrictions on this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some typos in your question. First of all, this is not a Cobb-Douglas function. Second, the exponents seem to be incorrect.

Nevertheless, let us change the utility function to a Cobb-Douglas case (as was meant in your question):

\begin{align}
u(x, y) = x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}.
\end{align}

Let us, for the sake of readability, change the prices to $p_x$ (instead of $p$) and $p_y$ (instead of q). The optimization problem is quite simple in this case and reads
\begin{equation}
\max_{x, y} \mathcal{L} = x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}- \lambda\left(p_xx + p_yy - m\right).
\end{equation}

The corresponding first-order conditions read
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} &= \alpha x^{\alpha-1}y^{1-\alpha}- \lambda p_x =0 \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} &= (1-\alpha)x^{\alpha}y^{-\alpha} - \lambda p_y =0 
\end{align}

It follows that
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\frac{p_x}{p_y}x \\
x(y) &= \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\frac{p_y}{p_x}y \\
\end{align}

All you need to do is to use the expression for $x$ and put it into your budget constraint to find a solution for $y$. Alternatively, you can use the expression for $y$ and find a solution for $x$. You will get exactly the same results. In the latter case, you will find
\begin{align}
m = p_xx + p_y\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\frac{p_x}{p_y}x,
\end{align}
which simplifies to
\begin{align}
m &= x\left(p_x\left[1+\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right]\right)\\
m &= x\frac{p_x}{\alpha}
\end{align}
Your solution for $x^\star$ is then given by $x^\star=\frac{\alpha}{p_x}m$. Put this expression for $x^\star$ into the expression for $y(x)$ from above to get $y^\star = \frac{1-\alpha}{p_y}m$.

Comment: I've edited the question and fixed the typos, hopefully it's better now!